# Naming of `pure` function in Control.Applicative

Tags: haskell, applicative

Why is the function for lifting a value into a functor named `pure` in Control.Applicative?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not about a practical programming problem, as laid out in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Think of `pure` as an adjective.

`foo <*> pure 4` = `foo` applied on a **pure** value `4`.

(As for the exact *reason* why it's called `pure`, probably only McBride and Paterson will know.)

Comment: Thanks. I was sort of wondering about the *why*, but if I understand you right, that's pretty arbitrary.

Answer (score 8):

It's a little like `fromInteger`. Its argument is always a pure value or function that will be lifted into the functor. Perhaps it should have been `fromPure` but you know how Haskell people love to shorten names (e.g. `fst` and `snd` instead of `first` and `second`...).

Comment: Note that `first` and `second` are functions too, in `Control.Arrow`.  I'm pretty sure they came later though.

Comment: Hmm. I thought `fst` and `snd` came from ML, but that's based only on the fact that ML is older than Haskell. A quick search reveals a paper ["ML under Unix on the VAX"](http://lucacardelli.name/Papers/MLUnix.pdf) that appears to be from the mid-80s (it cites no references newer than 1983, and tells how to install ML from a tape). The paper uses `fst` and `snd`, so it looks like my assumption wasn't too far off.

Comment: `fst` and `snd` have been in Haskell since I started using the language (1992) and Hughes paper introducing arrows came out in 2000. I would name the arrow functions `onFirst` and `onSecond`, I guess.