# (<*>) without having to wrap the second argument

Tags: haskell, functor, applicative

Haskell newbie here.
So `(<$>)` is defined as

```
(<$>) :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

And `(<*>)` is defined as

```
(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

But I feel like `Applicative` is two concepts in one:

1. One would be that of a functor
2. And one would be this:

```
(<@>) :: MyConcept m => m (a -> b) -> a -> b
```

So e.g. thinking in terms of `Maybe`:

I have an `let i = 4` and I have a `let foo = Nothing :: Num a => Maybe (a -> a)`.
Basically I have a function that may or may not be there, that takes an Int and returns an Int, and an actual Int.

Of course I could just wrap `i` by saying:

```
foo <*> Just i
```

But that requires me to know the what Applicative `foo` is wrapped in.
Is there something equivalent to what I described here? How would I go about implementing that function `<@>` myself?

It would be something like this:

```
let (<@>) func i = func <*> ??? i
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `pure`:

```
pure :: Applicative f => a -> f a

foo <*> pure i
```

although you could just use `fmap`:

```
fmap (\f -> f i) foo
```

or

```
fmap ($ i) foo
```

Comment: Thank you! Isn't `pure` not somehow misleading? From the name I would somehow expect the complete opposite. e.g. `let impure = pure :: a -> IO a`. Is there some reason?

Comment: @hgiesel it is [just a name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435308/naming-of-pure-function-in-control-applicative) and has nothing to do with purity.

Comment: @hgiesel I read `pure x` as "inject the pure value `x` in the applicative" (even if this reading would imply that applicative values are somehow impure, which is not the case...)

Answer (score 3):

```
(<@>) :: MyConcept m => m (a -> b) -> a -> b
```

To see if this is like an Applicative try deriving `<@>` from `<*>` and `pure`. You will find that it is impossible.

Where you can find `<@>` in a more general form is `extract :: (Counit w) => w a -> a` for [comonads](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/definitive-base-2.3/docs/Algebra-Classes.html#t:Comonad).

Can you implement `extract` for `Maybe`? What do you do when the value is `Nothing`?